XSD specify occurrence fits value in xml
If I have an element in an xml that is an integer representing a count n. And if I have an element with a sequence of elements that have an attribute id that should start at 1 and go up till n.
Is there some way in xsd to assure that the sequence of elements start with attribute id=1 and that it is increased by one to each next element and stops at the number specified by the value of another element?
Thanks for the Feedback so far. I will have a look at it the next week.
An minimal example of an xml could look like this:
<root>
  <meta>
    <count>3</count>
  </meta>
  <data>
    <row id="1">2.1</row>
    <row id="2">3.6</row>
    <row id="3">5.4</row>
  </data>
</root>

So the value of meta.count should match the total occurrence of row elements and those elements should start from 1 up to count value.
I tried now something like this and found out, since I can't reach siblings in the test, I need to put the test to a higher element and that works.
I can't use the value of one of the element as maxOccurs though. But probably I can create a third test for that. Edit: Yes, one can compare the count of the rows with the value of count.
Thanks for the support.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" vc:minVersion="1.1">
            <xs:element name="row">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:float">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="meta">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="count" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="data">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="row"/>
                        <!-- <xs:element maxOccurs="root/meta/count" ref="row"/> -->
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(data/row) = meta/count"/>
        <xs:assert test="max(data/row/@id) = meta/count"/>
        <xs:assert test="every $x in (1 to meta/count) satisfies data/row[$x]/@id = $x"
                       xerces:message="Rule #2.1: attribute id shall start at 1 and go up till @total value."/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>



Did not find anything.  Here are the schema restrictions : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp

XSD 1.1 assert should be able to handle it.

While asking an XSD question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSD(s) that tries to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Please try the following solution via XSD 1.1 and Xerces.
Will minor adjustment it will work with Saxon, and other XSD 1.1 conformant processors.
Even in Python: Is it possible to validate an XML file against XSD 1.1 in Python?
It is using an assert with a quantified expression to express the desired logic.
One single assert is covering all required logic:

Sequence of elements start with attribute id=1
The increment is always 1.
The sequence value stops at the number specified by the value of
another element/attribute.

XML
<root total="5">
    <r id="1"/>
    <r id="2"/>
    <r id="3"/>
    <r id="4"/>
    <r id="5"/>
</root>

XSD 1.1 #1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="r"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="total" use="required" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:assert test="every $x in (1 to @total) satisfies r[$x]/@id = $x"
                       xerces:message="Rule #2.1: attribute id shall start at 1 and go up till @total value."/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="r">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

XSD 1.1 #2
Even better and more concise via deep-equal(). No need in any other asserts.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           xmlns:xerces="http://xerces.apache.org" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="r"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="total" use="required" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:assert test="deep-equal((r/xs:int(@id)),(1 to @total))"
                       xerces:message="Rule #2.1: attribute id shall start at 1 and go up till @total value."/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="r">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


That looks promising. I didn't found out about the ref you are using. So far I figured out to declutter my xsd with defining types. Can one specify instead of maxOccurence="unbounded" something like maxOccurs="@total"? Is it possible to use the value of another element as total instead of the value of an attribute of an parent element?

Wishful thinking, I'm afraid.

@FordPrefect, I provided you a reliable working solution. Did you have a chance to try it?

Not yet, I think I can try it on Monday.

@YitzhakKhabinsky I tried now to transform your xsd example to my minimal example xml, and can't get it to work. Probably one can't reference sibblings in xsd assert.

I found the solution. Thanks for the help.

@FordPrefect, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. One single assert is covering all three pieces of the required logic. There is no need in any additional asserts.

Actually the one rule isn't sufficient. The test you defined checks that up to the total the id is ascending. But after that there could be more occurrences and the scheme would not detect an error. On the other hand in combination I could spare the middle assert, because if zhey are all ascending and the count matches the max id will be the count.

@FordPrefect, I concur.

@FordPrefect, please check XSD 1.1 #2

I will have a look.

So the r/xs:int(@id) is the array of all the id attribute values for all r's in order of appearance?

That's correct. Just it is called a sequence.

In XSD 1.1 you can write something like
<xs:element name="parent">
  ...
  <xs:assert test="every $child in ./child
                   satisfies @id = count($child/preceding-sibling::child)+1"/>
</xs:element>


Thanks for the hint. That solves the increasing order IG.
